# Moodle local plugins and save_file

Tags: moodle

I've created a working form within a local plugin and it is inserting data fine into my custom table.

What I want tyo add now is a filepicker element that upon saving the form puts the file into a specified folder.

The filep[icker itself works fine but when I save the form no file appears, the code I'm using looks like this:

`$mform->save_file('lowresCh', '/my_form/', false);`

I've tried various things in the 'my_form' bit, but to no avail. The rest of the form still puts its data into the custom table and I can see my file in the mdl_files table (marked as draft).

With full debugging on I can get a warning of:

`Warning: copy(/my_form/): failed to open stream: Is a directory in /...../lib/filestorage/stored_file.php on line 390`

I don't know if I'm approaching it incorrectly or not, any help or pointers in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Oh and I have read the [Using the File API in Moodle forms](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Using_the_File_API_in_Moodle_forms) page, useful in getting me to the point I'm at, but no further.

Comment: Sort of solved it, the save_file() command takes the file name rather than the directory, still would be nice if I could get the files put into a custom directory though.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using the filename as the second argument in save_file() and if I prepend a directory then all of the files will be saved within my plugin in a sub directory which is perfect.

So it looks like this now:

`$mform->save_file('lowresCh', 'files/'.$mform->get_new_filename('lowresCh'), false);`